# Where are iOS7 system wallpapers?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone, ssh

Where are iOS7 system wallpapers in the file system?

P.S. accessible with iFile or ssh (jailbroken).

e.g. /var/mobile/...

Answer (score 2):

**/Library/Wallpaper** is a symlink to the relevant location on the device.

The actual location is `/var/stash/Wallpaper.xxxxxx/<iOSdevice>` with xxxxxx being a generated string and <iOSdevice> being the type of iOS device (e.g. iPhone). The wallpapers are contained within this folder along with the thumbnails.